# Difference between onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" and form submit

Tags: javascript, html

Inside a form I have a button. What is the difference between when I submit the form via JavaScript like this

```
<button onclick="document.forms[0].submit();">
```

and when I submit it like this

```
<button type="submit"></button>?
```

The first one works for me with most browsers except webkit-based. The latter works fine as well.  No difference in functionality is apparent to me.  Is there one?

Comment: The first one works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/ZUuSw/ in chrome and safari

Comment: Not in my case. So whats the difference between the to ways of posting. One work the other don't.

Comment: I guess you should enable javascript then

Comment: In that case it's working like I said - the form should indeed submit through javascript by clicking that button which executes javascript to submit the first form in the document...

Comment: I have never said it didn't. But I guess my situation is rather unique. When posting via Javascript the post is submitted and the Content-Type:text/html;charset= is set to UTF-8, when posting without javascript the Type:text/html;charset= is set to ISO-8859-1

Comment: That depends on the target form's `accept-charset` attribute as well as on the site's encoding, it should not matter whether you submit that form manually or via javascript I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first example:

```
<button onclick="document.forms[0].submit();">
```

...will do two things:

1. Its `onclick` will submit the *first* form in the document (i.e., the one specified by the 0 index in `forms[0]`).
2. It will submit the form it is in (if it is in a form) because a button with no `type` attribute specified will be a submit button by default.

This two-step double-submit behaviour can be seen in this quick-and-dirty demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fMwuX/ (and is likely to lead to weird behaviour that might be a bit confusing to debug). If the button isn't actually in a form then this won't be a problem.

The second example:

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```

Will simply submit the form it is in (if it is in one).

In my opinion the second option is definitely preferable for several reasons, including but not limited to:

1. It will work even if the user has JS disabled.
2. It doesn't hard-code a form index with `forms[0]`.
3. It is shorter and clearer.
4. It won't clash with other form submit validation.

Comment: Thanks, not really what I was searching for but i was not specific enough in my question. I guess my situation is rather unique. When posting via Javascript via webkit-based browsers the post is submitted and the Content-Type:text/html;charset= is set to UTF-8, when posting without javascript the Type:text/html;charset= is set to ISO-8859-1

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why the charset would be different.

Answer (score 3):

The javascript example will submit the first form in your HTML document while the second example will submit the form which wraps that button.

Answer (score 1):

`documents.forms[0].submit` will trigger the submission of the first form in your HTML page. Indeed, `documents.forms` contains all the forms of your document. You can access them with their name attribute or their index.

Then, the input of type `submit` in a form will trigger the submission of his parent form.

Answer (score -1):

As you've discovered, the first one makes the page not work in some circumstances, and is - for this, and other reasons - generally considered bad practice. Use the second.